# How to determine what version of Cordova was used to build a legacy app?

Tags: android, cordova

We have a legacy app built by an external company that was developed using the Cordova framework for creating mobile apps.

I am having some issues making changes and decided try to re-build it using the exact same version of Cordova that the original developers had used but unsure how to find this info out (the company no longer operate)

Is there way in to find this out by looking at a particular file or folder within my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you should look for "FrameworkVersion" at ".abproject" in the root of your project.

If that doesn't work -

Here is another solution - find the newest file in "your_app.apk" ( as you know apk is renamed zip files, so it content can be easily viewed with rar or zip ).
After that go to http://archive.apache.org/dist/cordova/ - and look for the newest cordova-x.x.x-src.zip, which was created before the newest file in your apk. In the most cases that's is what you looking for.

Comment: Cheers - found the cordova.js file when extracting the apk (was 3.5.1) :)